# Check all control forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I create a formGroup like this

```
this.availableSigners = new FormGroup({
        nameSigner: new FormControl(),
        mailSigner: new FormControl()
});
```

and in my html component I have this

```
<div *ngFor="let signer of signers;  let i = index">
                    <div class="form-row">
<div class="card-body col-md-4" style="padding-top: 0.75rem !important">
    <b>{{signer.name}}  {{signer.surname}} 
    </b>&nbsp;
 </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="form-row" >      
     <div class="col-md-4">
           <ng-select #mailDocumentSelect 
                  formControlName="mailSigner" [items]="mails"
                  bindValue="code" bindLabel="description"  
                  (click)="getMails()">
            </ng-select>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ng-select>
                                </ng-select>
  </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>   
                </div>
```

where signers is a list that is populate by a click and create a list of select mail.

My problem is that I'm trying to control that EVERY mailSigner's formcontrolname has value.

I create this function that is called by a click from another button

```
 getCompiledFeq(){

  if(this.availableSigners.get('mailSigner').value){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
```

But this control return true when there is just one selected value(and doesn't control every form control).

How can I control that every select form is valued?

Comment: can you take a snapshot of your form?

Comment: they said me to change the FormGroup now in this --  this.availableSigners = new FormGroup({
        mailSigner: new FormControl()
});   without the nameSigner cause it's never used

Comment: By the way I changed my getCompiledFeq() in this way `getCompiledFeq(){
    
    
    const controls = this.availableSigners.controls;
    for(const elem in controls){
      console.log('elemzz ', controls[elem].value);
      if(controls[elem].value){
          return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
      
      } }`    but it seems not work

Comment: Are you having a form with multiple form controls with the same name??
Can you take a snapshot, I am not quite sure how does your form look like

Comment: yes there is a form with multiple form controls with the same name.. I can't take a snapshot

Comment: that is the problem, you should have a unique name for every control

Comment: "form with multiple form controls with the same name" --> feels like you rather need a `FormArray` than a `FormGroup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple form controls with the same name.

You can differ them with an index.

In your ts file, you need to loop throw all your signers and add a control for each signer with an unique id, like this

```
   this.availableSigners = new FormGroup({
            nameSigner: new FormControl(),
            mailSigners: new FormArray()
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < signers.length; i++) {
             this.availableSigners.get('mailSigners').push('mailSigner-' + i , new FormControl('', Validators.required));
     }
```

And in your html file change `formControlName` to "mailSigner-{{i}}" in order to have an unique index

```
<div *ngFor="let signer of signers;  let i = index">
                    <div class="form-row">
<div class="card-body col-md-4" style="padding-top: 0.75rem !important">
    <b>{{signer.name}}  {{signer.surname}} 
    </b>&nbsp;
 </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="form-row" >      
     <div class="col-md-4">
           <ng-select #mailDocumentSelect 
                  formControlName="mailSigner-{{i}}" [items]="mails"
                  bindValue="code" bindLabel="description"  
                  (click)="getMails()">
            </ng-select>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ng-select>
                                </ng-select>
  </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>   
                </div>
```

Comment: wow this works like a charm.. yeah there was a mistake at the beginning to create the right formcontrol. Thank you very much

Comment: Looks like Pyua should use a FormArray, wouldn't he?

Comment: You are right, by convention, it is better to use FormArray. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Validators` and making nameSigner a required field?
Your `FormGroup` will then only be `valid`, if all `FormControl`s that have a required Validator are filled.

making the control required:

```
this.availableSigners = new FormGroup({
        nameSigner: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        mailSigner: new FormControl()
});
```

check if all have a value:

```
getCompiledFeq(){

  if(this.availableSigners.valid){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
```

Angular Documentation for `Validators`:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation

Comment: but this return true also when there is a selected value and don't control every formcontrolname( I can have multiple formcontrolname with the same name

Comment: The valid refers to the FormGroup. You have to place all the FormControls you want to be checked in that FormGroup. FormGroups can also be nested, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From that forms you first set as nullValidator as your suggestion you set as required means

```
//Add in your TS and check
   get form() { return this.availableSigners .controls }
```

that form is you add

```
 if(this.availableSigners.valid){
     return true;
  }
else{
for(let i in this.availableSigners.controls){
  this.availableSigners.controls[i].markAsTouched();
}
}
 }
```

Comment: but this return true also when there is a selected value and don't control every formcontrolname( I can have multiple formcontrolname with the same name